# make errors while installing Open Semantic Framework v1.0

Tags: php, makefile, ubuntu-14.04, virtuoso

I am up to step 5 of the [StructWSF Installation Guide](http://wiki.opensemanticframework.org/index.php/Archive_1.x:StructWSF_Installation_Guide#STEP_5:_INSTALL_AND_TEST_VIRTUOSO_SERVER) (part of the [Open Semantic Framework](http://wiki.opensemanticframework.org/)), and trying to install Virtuoso 6.1.6. The `./configure` step is OK, but when running `sudo make`, and `sudo make check`, a lot of errors occur. It looks like a type of errors, but I have no clue on it.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04. Does anyone have some ideas?

Many thanks.

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/tmp/virtuoso-opensource-6.1.6$ sudo make check
Making check in .
make[1]: Entering directory `/tmp/virtuoso-opensource-6.1.6'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `check-am'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/virtuoso-opensource-6.1.6'
Making check in docsrc
make[1]: Entering directory `/tmp/virtuoso-opensource-6.1.6/docsrc'
Making check in chm
make[2]: Entering directory `/tmp/virtuoso-opensource-6.1.6/docsrc/chm'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `check'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/tmp/virtuoso-opensource-6.1.6/docsrc/chm'
Making check in docwiki
make[2]: Entering directory `/tmp/virtuoso-opensource-6.1.6/docsrc/docwiki'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `check'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/tmp/virtuoso-opensource-6.1.6/docsrc/docwiki'
Making check in html_virt
make[2]: Entering directory `/tmp/virtuoso-opensource-6.1.6/docsrc/html_virt'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `check'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/tmp/virtuoso-opensource-6.1.6/docsrc/html_virt'
Making check in images
make[2]: Entering directory `/tmp/virtuoso-opensource-6.1.6/docsrc/images'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `check'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/tmp/virtuoso-opensource-6.1.6/docsrc/images'
Making check in pdf
make[2]: Entering directory `/tmp/virtuoso-opensource-6.1.6/docsrc/pdf'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `check'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/tmp/virtuoso-opensource-6.1.6/docsrc/pdf'
Making check in releasenotes
make[2]: Entering directory `/tmp/virtuoso-opensource-6.1.6/docsrc/releasenotes'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `check'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/tmp/virtuoso-opensource-6.1.6/docsrc/releasenotes'
Making check in styleguide
make[2]: Entering directory `/tmp/virtuoso-opensource-6.1.6/docsrc/styleguide'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `check'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/tmp/virtuoso-opensource-6.1.6/docsrc/styleguide'
Making check in stylesheets
make[2]: Entering directory `/tmp/virtuoso-opensource-6.1.6/docsrc/stylesheets'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `check'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/tmp/virtuoso-opensource-6.1.6/docsrc/stylesheets'
Making check in xmlsource
make[2]: Entering directory `/tmp/virtuoso-opensource-6.1.6/docsrc/xmlsource'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `check'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/tmp/virtuoso-opensource-6.1.6/docsrc/xmlsource'
make[2]: Entering directory `/tmp/virtuoso-opensource-6.1.6/docsrc'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `check-am'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/tmp/virtuoso-opensource-6.1.6/docsrc'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/virtuoso-opensource-6.1.6/docsrc'
Making check in libsrc
make[1]: Entering directory `/tmp/virtuoso-opensource-6.1.6/libsrc'
Making check in util
make[2]: Entering directory `/tmp/virtuoso-opensource-6.1.6/libsrc/util'
make  check-am
make[3]: Entering directory `/tmp/virtuoso-opensource-6.1.6/libsrc/util'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `check-am'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/tmp/virtuoso-opensource-6.1.6/libsrc/util'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/tmp/virtuoso-opensource-6.1.6/libsrc/util'
Making check in zlib
make[2]: Entering directory `/tmp/virtuoso-opensource-6.1.6/libsrc/zlib'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `check'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/tmp/virtuoso-opensource-6.1.6/libsrc/zlib'
Making check in odbcsdk
make[2]: Entering directory `/tmp/virtuoso-opensource-6.1.6/libsrc/odbcsdk'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `check'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/tmp/virtuoso-opensource-6.1.6/libsrc/odbcsdk'
Making check in Dk
make[2]: Entering directory `/tmp/virtuoso-opensource-6.1.6/libsrc/Dk'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/tmp/virtuoso-opensource-6.1.6/libsrc/Dk'
Making check in Thread
make[2]: Entering directory `/tmp/virtuoso-opensource-6.1.6/libsrc/Thread'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `check'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/tmp/virtuoso-opensource-6.1.6/libsrc/Thread'
Making check in langfunc
make[2]: Entering directory `/tmp/virtuoso-opensource-6.1.6/libsrc/langfunc'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `check'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/tmp/virtuoso-opensource-6.1.6/libsrc/langfunc'
Making check in Wi
make[2]: Entering directory `/tmp/virtuoso-opensource-6.1.6/libsrc/Wi'
make  check-am
make[3]: Entering directory `/tmp/virtuoso-opensource-6.1.6/libsrc/Wi'
/bin/bash ../../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../libsrc/Dk    -fno-st                                                                  rict-aliasing -O2  -Wall  -DNDEBUG -DPOINTER_64  -I/usr/include  -I/tmp/virtuoso-opensource-6.1.6/libs                                                                  rc/Xml.new  -DOPENSSL_NO_KRB5 -Dlinux -D_GNU_SOURCE -DFILE64 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE   -I../../libsrc -I                                                                  ../../libsrc/Dk  -I. -I../../libsrc/langfunc -I../../libsrc/plugin -I../../libsrc/Tidy -I../../libsrc/                                                                  Xml.new -I../../libsrc/odbcsdk/include -DVAD -DDBP -DBIF_XPER -DOPSYS=\"Linux\" -DHOST=\"x86_64-unknow                                                                  n-linux-gnu\" -g -O2 -MT libwi_la-bif_crypto.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libwi_la-bif_crypto.Tpo -c -o libwi_                                                                  la-bif_crypto.lo `test -f 'bif_crypto.c' || echo './'`bif_crypto.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../libsrc/Dk -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -Wall -DNDEBUG -                                                                  DPOINTER_64 -I/usr/include -I/tmp/virtuoso-opensource-6.1.6/libsrc/Xml.new -DOPENSSL_NO_KRB5 -Dlinux -                                                                  D_GNU_SOURCE -DFILE64 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -I../../libsrc -I../../libsrc/Dk -I. -I../../libsrc/langfu                                                                  nc -I../../libsrc/plugin -I../../libsrc/Tidy -I../../libsrc/Xml.new -I../../libsrc/odbcsdk/include -DV                                                                  AD -DDBP -DBIF_XPER -DOPSYS=\"Linux\" -DHOST=\"x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu\" -g -O2 -MT libwi_la-bif_cryp                                                                  to.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libwi_la-bif_crypto.Tpo -c bif_crypto.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/libwi_la-bif_cry                                                                  pto.o
In file included from bif_crypto.c:36:0:
xmlenc.h:315:7: error: unknown type name 'des_cblock'
       des_cblock k1;
       ^
xmlenc.h:316:7: error: unknown type name 'des_cblock'
       des_cblock k2;
       ^
xmlenc.h:317:7: error: unknown type name 'des_cblock'
       des_cblock k3;
       ^
xmlenc.h:319:7: error: unknown type name 'des_key_schedule'
       des_key_schedule ks1;/* key schedule */
       ^
xmlenc.h:320:7: error: unknown type name 'des_key_schedule'
       des_key_schedule ks2;/* key schedule (for ede) */
       ^
xmlenc.h:321:7: error: unknown type name 'des_key_schedule'
       des_key_schedule ks3;/* key schedule (for ede3) */
       ^
xmlenc.h:323:7: error: unknown type name 'des_cblock'
       des_cblock iv;
       ^
bif_crypto.c: In function 'box_hmac':
bif_crypto.c:184:12: error: storage size of 'ctx' isn't known
   HMAC_CTX ctx;
            ^
bif_crypto.c:190:3: warning: 'HMAC_Init' is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/openssl/hmac.h:28) [-                                                                  Wdeprecated-declarations]
   HMAC_Init (&ctx, key, box_length (key) - DV_STRINGP (key) ? 1 : 0, md);
   ^
bif_crypto.c:184:12: warning: unused variable 'ctx' [-Wunused-variable]
   HMAC_CTX ctx;
            ^
bif_crypto.c: In function 'asn1_parse_to_xml':
bif_crypto.c:251:7: warning: passing argument 1 of 'ASN1_get_object' from incompatible pointer type [e                                                                  nabled by default]
       j = ASN1_get_object (&p, &len, &tag, &xclass, length);
       ^
In file included from /usr/include/openssl/objects.h:916:0,
                 from /usr/include/openssl/evp.h:27,
                 from xmlenc.h:35,
                 from bif_crypto.c:36:
/usr/include/openssl/asn1.h:671:5: note: expected 'const unsigned char **' but argument is of type 'un                                                                  signed char **'
 int ASN1_get_object(const unsigned char **pp, long *plength, int *ptag,
     ^
bif_crypto.c:335:8: warning: passing argument 2 of 'd2i_ASN1_OBJECT' from incompatible pointer type [e                                                                  nabled by default]
        if (d2i_ASN1_OBJECT (&o, &opp, len + hl) != NULL)
        ^
In file included from /usr/include/openssl/objects.h:916:0,
                 from /usr/include/openssl/evp.h:27,
                 from xmlenc.h:35,
                 from bif_crypto.c:36:
/usr/include/openssl/asn1.h:530:14: note: expected 'const unsigned char **' but argument is of type 'u                                                                  nsigned char **'
 ASN1_OBJECT *d2i_ASN1_OBJECT(ASN1_OBJECT **a, const unsigned char **pp,
              ^
bif_crypto.c:351:8: warning: implicit declaration of function 'd2i_ASN1_BOOLEAN' [-Wimplicit-function-                                                                  declaration]
        ii = d2i_ASN1_BOOLEAN (NULL, &opp, len + hl);
        ^
bif_crypto.c:368:8: warning: passing argument 2 of 'd2i_ASN1_OCTET_STRING' from incompatible pointer t                                                                  ype [enabled by default]
        os = d2i_ASN1_OCTET_STRING (NULL, &opp, len + hl);
        ^
In file included from /usr/include/openssl/objects.h:916:0,
                 from /usr/include/openssl/evp.h:27,
                 from xmlenc.h:35,
                 from bif_crypto.c:36:
/usr/include/openssl/asn1.h:594:1: note: expected 'const unsigned char **' but argument is of type 'un                                                                  signed char **'
 DECLARE_ASN1_FUNCTIONS(ASN1_OCTET_STRING)
 ^
bif_crypto.c:418:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'M_ASN1_OCTET_STRING_free' [-Wimplicit-f                                                                  unction-declaration]
     M_ASN1_OCTET_STRING_free (os);
     ^
bif_crypto.c:428:8: warning: passing argument 2 of 'd2i_ASN1_INTEGER' from incompatible pointer type [                                                                  enabled by default]
        bs = d2i_ASN1_INTEGER (NULL, &opp, len + hl);
        ^
In file included from /usr/include/openssl/objects.h:916:0,
                 from /usr/include/openssl/evp.h:27,
                 from xmlenc.h:35,
                 from bif_crypto.c:36:
/usr/include/openssl/asn1.h:569:1: note: expected 'const unsigned char **' but argument is of type 'un                                                                  signed char **'
 DECLARE_ASN1_FUNCTIONS(ASN1_INTEGER)
 ^
bif_crypto.c:451:8: warning: implicit declaration of function 'M_ASN1_INTEGER_free' [-Wimplicit-functi                                                                  on-declaration]
        M_ASN1_INTEGER_free (bs);
        ^
bif_crypto.c:459:8: warning: passing argument 2 of 'd2i_ASN1_ENUMERATED' from incompatible pointer typ                                                                  e [enabled by default]
        bs = d2i_ASN1_ENUMERATED (NULL, &opp, len + hl);
        ^
In file included from /usr/include/openssl/objects.h:916:0,
                 from /usr/include/openssl/evp.h:27,
                 from xmlenc.h:35,
                 from bif_crypto.c:36:
/usr/include/openssl/asn1.h:575:1: note: expected 'const unsigned char **' but argument is of type 'un                                                                  signed char **'
 DECLARE_ASN1_FUNCTIONS(ASN1_ENUMERATED)
 ^
bif_crypto.c:482:8: warning: implicit declaration of function 'M_ASN1_ENUMERATED_free' [-Wimplicit-fun                                                                  ction-declaration]
        M_ASN1_ENUMERATED_free (bs);
        ^
bif_crypto.c: In function 'bif_smime_sign':
bif_crypto.c:857:21: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
   if (store && store->objs)
                     ^
bif_crypto.c:859:52: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
       for (inx = 0; inx < sk_X509_OBJECT_num (store->objs); inx++)
                                                    ^
bif_crypto.c:861:50: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
    X509_OBJECT *obj = sk_X509_OBJECT_value (store->objs, inx);
                                                  ^
bif_crypto.c:862:11: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
    if (obj->type == X509_LU_X509)
           ^
bif_crypto.c:863:40: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
      sk_X509_push (certs, X509_dup (obj->data.x509));
                                        ^
bif_crypto.c: In function 'bif_smime_encrypt':
bif_crypto.c:938:21: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
   if (store && store->objs)
                     ^
bif_crypto.c:940:52: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
       for (inx = 0; inx < sk_X509_OBJECT_num (store->objs); inx++)
                                                    ^
bif_crypto.c:942:50: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
    X509_OBJECT *obj = sk_X509_OBJECT_value (store->objs, inx);
                                                  ^
bif_crypto.c:943:11: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
    if (obj->type == X509_LU_X509)
           ^
bif_crypto.c:944:40: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
      sk_X509_push (certs, X509_dup (obj->data.x509));
                                        ^
bif_crypto.c: In function 'x509_certificate_verify_cb':
bif_crypto.c:1114:18: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
       switch (ctx->error)
                  ^
bif_crypto.c: In function 'bif_x509_certificate_verify':
bif_crypto.c:1211:51: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
       err_str = X509_verify_cert_error_string (csc->error);
                                                   ^
bif_crypto.c: In function 'BN_box':
bif_crypto.c:1238:37: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
     buf = box_num ((unsigned long) x->d[0]);
                                     ^
bif_crypto.c: In function 'bif_get_certificate_info':
bif_crypto.c:1422:41: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
  STACK_OF (X509_EXTENSION) * exts = cert->cert_info->extensions;
bif_crypto.c:1434:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'M_ASN1_OCTET_STRING_print' [-Wimplicit                                                                  -function-declaration]
     M_ASN1_OCTET_STRING_print (mem, ex->value);
     ^
bif_crypto.c:1434:39: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
     M_ASN1_OCTET_STRING_print (mem, ex->value);
                                       ^
bif_crypto.c:1461:11: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
      if (k->type == EVP_PKEY_RSA)
           ^
bif_crypto.c:1463:13: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
   RSA *x = k->pkey.rsa;
             ^
bif_crypto.c:1464:65: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
   ret = list (3, box_dv_short_string ("RSAPublicKey"), BN_box (x->e), BN_box (x->n));
                                                                 ^
bif_crypto.c:1464:80: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
   ret = list (3, box_dv_short_string ("RSAPublicKey"), BN_box (x->e), BN_box (x->n));
                                                                                ^
bif_crypto.c:1469:11: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
      if (k->type == EVP_PKEY_DSA)
           ^
bif_crypto.c:1471:13: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
   DSA *x = k->pkey.dsa;
             ^
bif_crypto.c:1472:65: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
   ret = list (2, box_dv_short_string ("DSAPublicKey"), BN_box (x->pub_key));
                                                                 ^
bif_crypto.c:1491:61: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
  for (i = 0; NULL != subj && i < sk_X509_NAME_ENTRY_num(subj->entries); i++)
                                                             ^
bif_crypto.c:1493:40: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
      ne = sk_X509_NAME_ENTRY_value(subj->entries,i);
                                        ^
bif_crypto.c:1494:25: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
      n = OBJ_obj2nid (ne->object);
                         ^
bif_crypto.c:1495:34: warning: assignment discards 'const' qualifier from pointer target type [enabled                                                                   by default]
      if ((n == NID_undef) || ((s = OBJ_nid2sn (n)) == NULL))
                                  ^
bif_crypto.c:1497:47: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
   i2t_ASN1_OBJECT (buffer, sizeof (buffer), ne->object);
                                               ^
bif_crypto.c:1508:36: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
      ASN1_STRING_print (mem, ne_ret->value);
                                    ^
bif_crypto.c:1529:61: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
  for (i = 0; NULL != subj && i < sk_X509_NAME_ENTRY_num(subj->entries); i++)
                                                             ^
bif_crypto.c:1532:40: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
      ne = sk_X509_NAME_ENTRY_value(subj->entries,i);
                                        ^
bif_crypto.c:1533:25: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
      n = OBJ_obj2nid (ne->object);
                         ^
bif_crypto.c:1534:34: warning: assignment discards 'const' qualifier from pointer target type [enabled                                                                   by default]
      if ((n == NID_undef) || ((s = OBJ_nid2sn (n)) == NULL))
                                  ^
bif_crypto.c:1536:47: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
   i2t_ASN1_OBJECT (buffer, sizeof (buffer), ne->object);
                                               ^
bif_crypto.c:1539:32: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
      ASN1_STRING_print (mem, ne->value);
                                ^
make[3]: *** [libwi_la-bif_crypto.lo] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/tmp/virtuoso-opensource-6.1.6/libsrc/Wi'
make[2]: *** [check] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/tmp/virtuoso-opensource-6.1.6/libsrc/Wi'
make[1]: *** [check-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/virtuoso-opensource-6.1.6/libsrc'
make: *** [check-recursive] Error 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I would start with an update/upgrade of Virtuoso to a more recent version. [Version 7.2.4.2](http://vos.openlinksw.com/owiki/wiki/VOS/VOSNews) or later is considered current and strongly recommended; [Version 6.1.8](http://vos.openlinksw.com/owiki/wiki/VOS/VOSNews2013) was the last v6 and the last 32-bit (v7 is 64-bit only).

Either way, you might consider following [official Virtuoso instructions](http://vos.openlinksw.com/owiki/wiki/VOS#Download%2C%20Build%2C%20and%20Use%20--%20Get%20Started!), especially including installation of the [build dependencies](http://vos.openlinksw.com/owiki/wiki/VOS/VOSUbuntuNotes#Dependencies), instead of a very old (last updated 2012-12-17!) third-party guide.

(Indeed, why are you not even working with the [current OSF Installer](http://wiki.opensemanticframework.org/index.php/OSF_Installer), given that you're on a current Ubuntu?)

(ObDisclaimer: [OpenLink Software](https://www.openlinksw.com/) produces [Virtuoso](https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/), and employs me.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I didn't even notice that the version 6.16 is 32-bit! I was intending to use the OSF installer to install OSF(including virtuoso), but there were always some errors when loading ontologies at the last step, then I was thinking why not try to install it step by step, that's why I go to the osf instructions above. Now I will try the virtuoso v7 as you said it's for 64-bit, and see if it works. Thanks again!

Comment: To be clearer, v6 may be built as either 32-bit or 64-bit. v7 cannot be built as 32-bit. Please do also note -- you have been working with manual build steps for OSF v1, while current OSF is v3. And… the issues you encountered with loading ontologies seem unlikely to be caused by build/install issues. It seems you may be razing-and-rebuilding a house because a couch didn't fit through the door.

Comment: Hi TallTed, thanks for clarifying this, and I found this indeed was not related to the install issues, this may be because of the php version I use, I am using php5.6 while the OSF installer (by following this procedure:https://github.com/structureddynamics/Open-Semantic-Framework-Installer) configures the .ini file of php5, they have different .ini files. And when I noticed this problem I changed the system configuration with php5, and the installation succeeded!

Comment: The mix of old-and-new software you've described is almost certain to lead to other issues down the line. I strongly advise that you assemble a kit of similarly aged versions, optimally (near) current!

Comment: Yes, indeed. I will close this question by giving an answer down here. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

To close this question:

This issue is probably related to the php version not fitting the [osf installer](https://github.com/structureddynamics/Open-Semantic-Framework-Installer) requirements when my environment was Ubuntu14.04, apache2, php5.6, mysql5.

However, this installer is only taking php5 into consideration(the .ini file position is different with php5.6's, I know this by checking the installation php file), that's why some of the software doesn't work well, while degrading php5.6 to php5 works well for me.

Now my environment becomes Ubuntu14.04, apache2, **php5**, mysql5, and the installation is working well.

Hope this could help someone.